# pandoc support for LaTeX ctable?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I use `ctable` to make my LaTeX tables. My ultimate goal is to produce a presentation of HTML5 slides. The tables that I need to present are all created in LaTeX with `ctable`.

For example, I have my LaTeX `ctable` saved in `table.tex`. Then I try

```
pandoc -s table.tex -o table.md
```

to create a markdown version of the table, so that I can then use

```
pandoc -s --mathjax -S -i -t slidy table.md -o table.html
```

to produce the HTML5 slides. However, the first step

```
pandoc -s table.tex -o table.md
```

just produces a completely empty file table.md.

How can create an HTML5 slideshow with tables created in LaTeX `ctable`?

Here is an example `ctable`, so this code would be the contents of `table.tex` referenced above.

```
\ctable[botcap,caption={Basic descriptive statistics for GSS data},label=tab:gss1,pos=!tbp,]{lrrr}{}{\FL
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{N}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{mean}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{std. dev.}\ML
age&$1969$&$   48.19$&$   17.69$\NN
children&$1971$&$    1.89$&$    1.67$\NN
income&$1142$&$27580.59$&$57601.05$\LL
}
```

Comment: You should ask your (La)TeX questions on [tex.se].

Comment: But it's not a latex question.  I want to generate markdown and html output from the latex input.  The latex input is fine, and I can generate ps and pdf output from the latex as it is fine.

Comment: I want to use this latex input to produce html5 slide output.  How to do that is my question

Comment: This isn't a LaTeX/TeX question as pandoc does not use tex.  You may get some helpful suggestions (especially as I've just seen that John MacFarlane has an account here) but in general, this isn't the place to post pandoc questions.

Answer (score 3):

Pandoc doesn't seem to support `ctable`. When it generates LaTeX tables from Markdown, for example, it uses `longtable`. See the [PDF requirements](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#creating-a-pdf).

Having said that, I haven't been able to get it to *parse* tables from LaTeX at all, regardless of the table implementation.

I see two options:

- **Change your input file format to something that Pandoc can fully ingest**, like its [enhanced Markdown format](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#pandocs-markdown). It supports [tables](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#tables) and [TeX-style math](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#math).

  I get the impression that you have made a significant investment in your existing source files, so this is unlikely to be a good solution for you.
- **Change your presentation format to PDF** and use something like [Beamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29) to generate your presentation directly from LaTeX.

  Incidentally, Pandoc supports Beamer output and handles it very well from Markdown source:

  `pandoc -s --mathjax -S -i -t beamer -R test.md -o test.pdf`

  You may also be able to tweak your `.tex` file and use the `-R` raw option to Pandoc to pass unrecognized LaTeX from your source file directly through to Beamer, though I haven't gotten this to work. I'm not enough of a LaTeX expert to troubleshoot this.

If HTML output and LaTeX input are both non-negotiable, you may be stuck tweaking tables manually as you do your conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write the table data in a latex `\begin{table} foo \end{table}`, You can convert to HTML and more types such as JSON, Markdown, CSV likewise using a website called https://tableconvert.com/latex-to-latex.

Another option is available on the site where you manually enter the data (no `\begin{table} foo \end{table}` prequiste).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).